# Sliding subarray beauty working on IDE but not on leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, sliding-window

#### Problem

[2653. Sliding Subarray Beauty](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-subarray-beauty)

> Given an integer array `nums` containing `n` integers, find the beauty of
> each subarray of size `k`.
>
> The beauty of a subarray is the `xth` smallest integer in the subarray
> if it is negative, or 0 if there are fewer than `x` negative integers.
>
> Return an integer array containing `n - k + 1` integers, which denote
> the beauty of the subarrays in order from the first index in the
> array.

#### Code

```
class Solution(object):
    def getSubarrayBeauty(self, nums, k, x):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :type x: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        eleToFreq = {m: 0 for m in range(-50, 0)}
        i = j = 0
        toReturn = list()
        while j < len(nums):
            if j >= k - 1:
                if nums[j] < 0:
                    eleToFreq[nums[j]] += 1
                a = 0
                for key, value in eleToFreq.items():
                    if value > 0 and a == x - 1:
                        toReturn.append(key)
                        a += 1
                    elif value > 0:
                        a += value
                if a < x :
                    toReturn.append(0)
                if nums[i] < 0:
                    eleToFreq[nums[i]] -= 1
                i += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                if nums[j] < 0:
                    eleToFreq[nums[j]] += 1
                j += 1
        return toReturn


solution = Solution()
v = solution.getSubarrayBeauty([1, -1, -3, -2, 3], 3, 2)  # expected output [-1,-2,-2]
print(v)

v = solution.getSubarrayBeauty([-1, -2, -3, -4, -5], 2, 2)  # expected output [-1,-2,-3,-4]
print(v)

v = solution.getSubarrayBeauty([-3, 1, 2, -3, 0, -3], 2, 1)  # expected output [-3,0,-3,-3,-3]
print(v)

v = solution.getSubarrayBeauty([1,-1,-3,-2,3], 3, 2)  # expected output [-1,-2,-2]
print(v)

v = solution.getSubarrayBeauty([-43], 1, 1)  # expected output [-43]
print(v)
```

#### Issue

These cases work in IDE but not in Leetcode. I get all the expected answers in Intellij but same code gives me wrong answer in leetcode on the following cases

```
nums=[1,-1,-3,-2,3] k=3 x=2 expected output: [-1,-2,-2] actual output [-3,-3,-2]
nums=[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5] k=2 x=2 expected output: [-1,-2,-3,-4] actual output [-2,-2,-3,-4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result on your local environment is different from LeetCode's because you have chosen Python version 2 on the LeetCode site. Your algorithm needs the iteration of the dict `eleToFreq` to happen in insertion order. But [before Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/5459839) there was no guarantee that iteration over a dict would maintain insertion order.

The solution is to choose "Python3" instead of "Python" (which is version 2) as engine for your LeetCode submission.

#### Other issue

There is another problem though in your algorithm:

When `value` is greater than 1, and `a == x - 1` is not true, then there is no verification whether any other of the duplicates of `a` count as the x<sup>th</sup> occurrence. This test only verifies whether the *first* occurrence of `a` would be the x<sup>th</sup> occurrence.

To fix that issue, replace this code:

```
if value > 0 and a == x - 1:
    toReturn.append(key)
    a += 1
elif value > 0:
    a += value
```

...with this:

```
if value > 0 and a <= x - 1 < a + value:
    toReturn.append(key)
a += value
```

Comment: I don't understand the fix of ```a <= x - 1 < a + value``` but this change fixes this input ```[-18,-18,12] k=2 x=2``` expected output: was -18,0 but without fix was returning -18,0,0. Shouldn't we make sure a+value is less than x? because we dont want to go overboard? could you please explain?

Comment: As `a` is an index of where `key` occurs in sorted order, `a+value` is the *first* index that follows, where the value (in sorted order) is no longer `key`. So the section from index `a` to `a+value-1` (inclusive), contains the only value `key` (when in sorted order). If `x` happens to be one of `a`, `a+1`, ...`a+value-1`, then we have found the key that we must append (for this particular window). Using more descriptive variable names will help understand your code. `a` is not very meaninful.